# Proof that an $n \times n$ matrix is positive definite iff all of its eigenvalues are positive

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to prove that an $n \times n$ matrix is positive definite iff all of its eigenvalues are positive.

I know that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then:

$Ax = \lambda x$ for eigenvalues lambda. From there I can go to:

$x^TAx = x^T\lambda x$

Is there some special property of transpose matrices I can use to just get $\lambda$ on the right side of the equation? Because then the proof would pretty much be done.

Comment: You also need the condition that the matrix is symmetric: [positive-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^T\lambda x = \lambda x^Tx = \lambda ||x||^2$$

Comment: and $||x||^2$ is always positive, right?

Comment: @JorgeCastillo assuming $ x\neq 0$, yes ;-)